# Show that $x \le y \le 1$, $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le z \le 1-y^2$ implies $0 \le z \le 1$, $0 \le y \le \sqrt{1-z}$ and $0 \le x \le y$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How do I show that $x \le y \le 1$, $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le z \le 1-y^2$ implies $0 \le z \le 1$, $0 \le y \le \sqrt{1-z}$ and $0 \le x \le y$ without sketching it in three dimensions?

Comment: I think that there's a typo (are you sure about $1 \le z \le 1 - y^2$)?

Comment: @AhmedHussein Yeah, why is that a problem?

Comment: Well, because you can't have $1 \le 1 - y^2$ unless $y = 0$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AhmedHussein You're absolutely right, sorry. It should be $0 \le z \le 1-y^2$

Comment: You need to prove a number of things.Which ones are you having trouble with?

Comment: @GitGud  I see that my inequalities imply $ 0 \le x \le y$ - the rest, I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: Note that $0\leq x\leq y$. Now from $z\leq 1-y^2$ follows $y^2\leq 1-z$. Since $y^2$ is non-negative and $1-z$ isn't smaller than $y^2$, you can take the square root of both $y^2$ and $1-z$. Also recall that the square root function is increasing. This allows you to conclude what?

Comment: $y^2 \ge 0$ so $1-y^2 \le 1$ so $0\le z \le 1 -y^2 \le 1$.  $0 \le 0 \le x$ and $x \le y $ imply $y \ge 0$ so $0 \le z \le 1 -y^2$ means $0\le y^2 \le 1 - z $ so $0 \le y \le \sqrt {1-z} $.  F@@@ , I wouldn't know to solve this *by* sketching.